# Emails vacios, con php + Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

ya no se que hacer para que no me lleguen emails vacios, a pesar de ir probando distintos modos para que no puedan enviar un formulario si no rellenan todos los campos. Ahora mismo lo estoy haciendo así:

**El formulario**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="llamadaNosotros" method="post">
          <h3 class="teLlama">¡Dejanos tu teléfono y te llamamos!</h3>
          <p class="pteLlama">Rellena los datos y lo más pronto posible se pondrá un especialista en contacto contigo.</p>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-user form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-llamanos myInput2" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Persona de contacto" required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-llamanos myInput2" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" required>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <input type="checkbox" class="micheckbox336" id="micheckbox336" style="display:inline-block;">
            <label class="labTerm" style="display:inline;">He leído y acepto la <a href="privacidad-y-condiciones" title="Privacidad y Condiciones">Privacidad y Condiciones</a></label>
          </div>

          <div id="mens" style="text-align:center" style="margin-bottom:2%;">

          </div>

          <div class="center" style="margin-top:2%;">
            <button type="submit" id="llamada22" class="btn btn-primary btn-evniaMail" disabled>Enviar Mail <i id="airPlane2" class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right maRgairplane2" ></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**Luego con esto, hasta que no están los inputs llenos no se activa el botón enviar**

```
(function() {
var button = $('#llamada22');
var checkbox = $("#micheckbox336");
var inputs = $('.text-llamanos');

function switchButton(state){
  if(state === "off"){
    button.prop('disabled', true);
  }else if(state === "on"){
    button.prop('disabled', false);
  }
}

function inputsAreField(){
  var input_are_filled = true;
  inputs.each(function(index, input){
    if( $(input).val() === undefined ||
        $(input).val() === '' ||
        !$(input).val()){
      input_are_filled = false;
    }
  });
  return input_are_filled;
}

checkbox.change(function(){
  if(inputsAreField() && checkbox.is(":checked")){
    switchButton("on");
  }else{
    switchButton("off");
  }
});

inputs.each(function(index,input){
  $(input).keyup(function(){
     if(inputsAreField() && checkbox.is(":checked")){
        switchButton("on");
        return;
      }
      switchButton("off");
   });
});
```

**Y lo envio con AJAX**

```
$(function(){
   $("#llamadaNosotros").on("submit", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var f = $(this);
       var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("llamadaNosotros"));
       formData.append("dato", "valor");

       $.ajax({
           url: "respuestas/respuesta-llamada.php",
           type: "post",
           dataType: "html",
           data: formData,
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,

            beforeSend: function(){
             $("#mens").html("<div class='ui active inline loader myLoader' style='margin-bottom:1%;'></div>")
             },
            success: function (resultado){
             setTimeout(function(){
               $("#mens").html(resultado);
             }, 1300);
           }
         });
             setTimeout(function () {
               location.reload();
             }, 5000); //will call the function after 2 secs
      });
   });
```

Pero aun siendo así me llegan emails de los formularios vacios, ya no se como hacer, alguna idea?? Saludos

Comment: Me parece que te complicaste. En el evento submit, podes hacer la validación de los campos y si no tiene datos hacés return false, y eso cancela el submit.

Comment: Si pero necesitaba que el botón no se active hasta que este todo relleno, por tema de conversiones con el botón. Por eso se hizo de ese modo, puedo añadir igualmente validaciones? si es así como se hacen? gracias @Juan

Comment: La manera más sencilla de atajar tu problema es tener una función validadora que te devuelva un `true` o un `false` dependiendo de si los campos del formulario cumplen o no con las validaciones. Si esa función te devuelve que están todos validados, dentro del submit lanzas la llamada AJAX y si no las cumple pues informas al usuario de la manera que creas más conveniente (usualmente marcando los campos que no la cumplen de alguna manera)

Comment: A esa misma función podrías llamarla cada vez que uno de tus input cambie para saber si tienes o no que habilitar el botón de submit. Así es usable en diferentes circunstancias.

Comment: Yo creo que la validación en el front-end podrías hacerla de manera muy simple con un 'required' en tu input. De la siguiente manera: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monté un pequeño ejemplo en base a mis comentarios. Cree una función validadora que comprueba solamente si los campos están vacíos o no lo están. A esta función la llamo en el `change()` de cada `<input>` para habiliar o no el boton de *Enviar* y también la llamo en la función `submit()` como seguridad adicional para impedir o permitir la llamada **AJAX**.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#mi-formulario').submit(function (evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    
    let validado = validar_campos();
    
    if(validado) {
      console.log('Se lanza la llamada AJAX');
    }
    else {
      console.log('No se lanza la llamada AJAX');
    }
  });
  
  $('#mi-formulario input').change(function () {
    let validado = validar_campos();
    
    if (validado) {
      $('#enviar').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
      $('#enviar').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
})

function validar_campos() {
  let inputs = $('#mi-formulario input');
  let validado = true;
  
  inputs.each(function () {
    let input = $(this);
    let tipo_input = input.attr('type')
    let expresion = /\w/;
    
    if (tipo_input === 'checkbox') {
      if (!input.is(':checked')) {
        validado = false;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (!expresion.test(input.val())) {
        validado = false;
      }
    }
  });
  
  return validado;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mi-formulario">
  <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellidos">
  <input type="number" id="edad" placeholder="Edad">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="aceptar" value="aceptar"> Acepto las políticas.
  <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" disabled>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Añadí por expresión regular que los campos deban tener al menos un caracter alfanumérico para no considerarse vacíos (aunque esto no estuviese incluido en la pregunta) y también que el *checkbox* esté marcado.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan elaborada! pero creo que me pasaria lo mismo que me sucede ahora mismo, si ponen un espacio ya les cuenta como un caracter y activaria el botón, que opinas @phpMyGuel

Comment: Y este ejemplo tampoco haria lo del botón checkbox, es importante que lo marquen

Comment: Te he puesto ejemplos de validaciones entendiendo que sabías como validar si un check está o no seleccionado. De todas formas edité la respuesta para contemplar esas dos cosas que comentas.

Comment: Estupendo! funciona correctamente!!! eres un crack @phpMyGuel , gracias por tu ayuda! así ya no se lo podrán saltar no?

Comment: No, no podrían. Puedes probarlo dándole al botón ejecutar para tratar de buscarle las cosquillas al código ^^

Answer (score 0):

Unos consejos, las validaciones las tienes que ahcer tanto en el front end como en el back end ya que si algún usuario malicioso se brinca tu fron puede enviar datos no esperados.
En el front puedes validad todo con el simple required en todos los campos como o estás haciendo, solo inclúyelo en todos los campos o sea también pónselo al checkbox
En el back si usas php con estas líneas puedes validad

```
if(isset($_POST[‘nombredelcampo’])){
//codigo
}
```

Yo creo que con eso basta para validarlos muy bien, en el front, no te compliques tanto, si quieres mantener el botón inhabilitado solo ponlo deshabilitado y que cuando el check este checked si los inputs de texto tienen valor que active el boton